# Determining macroeconomic events

Tags: macroeconomics

Which of these events are macro economic events:

1)unemployment has increased over the past month

2)the pharmaceutical society invents a new medicine

3)the interest rates are decreasing for all borrowers

4)A bank lends money to a large corporation but denies a loan to a small business

5)Price of petrol increase

im really confused on whats the traits of choosing what is a macro-econ event

Comment: Hi @Mo. A so-called macro event is one in which the effects are transmitted through an entire domestic economy, and perhaps internationally too. **Unemployment** is a macro phenomenon. Not only does it affect a population directly, but there are indirect personal consumption effects alongside revenue effects for a government. You should also think of **fuel** as a macroeconomic good given the transmission of direct and indirect effects through an economy. The last of your answers, I shall leave for you to determine.